# Escape "~*" in a query param for NGINX

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I need send a query param with "~*" value to backend (for hibernate expression), but nginx capture it and response 404, how to escape it? I use nginx 1.15.0
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use the regex location, just include the args:

```
location ~* ^/service/(.*) {
  proxy_pass http://apache/$1$is_args$args;
}
```